# NumberFormatException - Azure Blob Listing

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to list the blobs from directory with azure file directory system.

But I am getting number format exception , please help me .

```
'''Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Wed, 24 Aug 2022 15:06:25 GMT"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:589)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:631)
    at com.azure.storage.file.datalake.Transforms.toPathItem(Transforms.java:351)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1384)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:708)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:499)
    at com.azure.storage.file.datalake.DataLakeFileSystemAsyncClient.lambda$listPathsWithOptionalTimeout$3(DataLakeFileSystemAsyncClient.java:708)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:113)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:249)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:74)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:191)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2398)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxHandleFuseable.java:257)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:171)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:2194)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:2068)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:96)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxHandleFuseable.java:161)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:55)
    at reactor.core.publisher.InternalMonoOperator.subscribe(InternalMonoOperator.java:64)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:157)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxContextWrite$ContextWriteSubscriber.onNext(FluxContextWrite.java:107)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:173)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoOnEach$DoOnEachFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxDoOnEach.java:281)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHide$SuppressFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHide.java:137)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDelaySubscription$DelaySubscriptionMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxDelaySubscription.java:189)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxTimeout$TimeoutMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxTimeout.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.complete(MonoIgnoreThen.java:292)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.onNext(MonoIgnoreThen.java:187)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:129)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1816)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:151)
    at reactor.core.publisher.SerializedSubscriber.onNext(SerializedSubscriber.java:99)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxRetryWhen$RetryWhenMainSubscriber.onNext(FluxRetryWhen.java:174)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onNext(FluxOnErrorResume.java:79)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoInnerProducerBase.complete(Operators.java:2664)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSingle$SingleSubscriber.onComplete(MonoSingle.java:180)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onComplete(MonoFlatMapMany.java:260)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:144)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxDoFinally$DoFinallySubscriber.onComplete(FluxDoFinally.java:128)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1817)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollect.java:160)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onComplete(FluxHandle.java:220)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMap.java:275)
    at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundComplete(FluxReceive.java:400)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundComplete(ChannelOperations.java:419)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.terminate(ChannelOperations.java:473)
    at reactor.netty.http.client.HttpClientOperations.onInboundNext(HttpClientOperations.java:703)
    at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:327)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:299)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1373)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeNonJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1247)
    at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1287)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:510)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:449)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:279)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:722)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:658)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:584)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:496)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
        at reactor.core.publisher.BlockingSingleSubscriber.blockingGet(BlockingSingleSubscriber.java:99)
        at reactor.core.publisher.Flux.blockLast(Flux.java:2645)
        at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedByIteratorBase.requestPage(ContinuablePagedByIteratorBase.java:102)
        at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedByItemIterable$ContinuablePagedByItemIterator.<init>(ContinuablePagedByItemIterable.java:75)
        at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedByItemIterable.iterator(ContinuablePagedByItemIterable.java:55)
        at com.azure.core.util.paging.ContinuablePagedIterable.iterator(ContinuablePagedIterable.java:141)
        at adlsconnection.ADLSConnection.listFilesInDirectory('''
```

Following is the code that I am using

```
    
    ListPathsOptions options = new ListPathsOptions();
    options.setPath("my-directory");
 
    PagedIterable<PathItem> pagedIterable = 
    fileSystemClient.listPaths(options, null);

    java.util.Iterator<PathItem> iterator = pagedIterable.iterator();

   
    PathItem item = iterator.next();

    while (item != null)
    {
        System.out.println(item.getName());


        if (!iterator.hasNext())
        {
            break;
        }
        
        item = iterator.next();
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, we are having the same error. Have you found solution for it ? We have noticed, that it is connected to one specific Azure instance, because the same code works with different account. Maybe some Locale/Region settings - but haven't found the resolution for it.

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced a similar issue. As James mentioned above, it is due to using APIs that work against ADLS gen2 only.
If you're setting up a new storage account, you can create an account with Gen2 storage directly as mentioned above:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/create-data-lake-storage-account#enable-the-hierarchical-namespace

In case, you've already setup an account, you can upgrade it to use ADLS gen2 as well. The only caveat is that all the containers in this account will be inaccessible during the upgrade, including UI access and any other hooks that you might have attached to these containers.
Here's how to go ahead with the upgrade.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/upgrade-to-data-lake-storage-gen2-how-to?tabs=azure-portal

Thanks a lot for the help
[@James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8627215/james-netherton!!)

Answer (score 0):

I observed a similar problem.

On the Azure storage account, you must enable the hierarchical namespace. Otherwise you're likely to encounter errors.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/create-data-lake-storage-account#enable-the-hierarchical-namespace